# git diff - compares index to HEAD? What about staging area and HEAD?

Tags: git, git-diff

So I have been confused about this for a while.

Does `git diff`, compare the `index` to `HEAD` by default? Or the `staging area` with `HEAD`?

Assuming `git diff` compares the index with HEAD, how would I run `git diff` between staging and HEAD instead of the index and HEAD?

Comment: the index _is_ the staging area.  `git diff` compares the working tree to the index by default, or the index to HEAD if you use `--cached`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare *working directory* with *staging / index* use:

```
git diff [--options] [--] [<path>…​]
```

This answers the question *What I have changed in files in this repo?*

To compare *staging / index* with *HEAD* (<commit> defaults to *HEAD*) use:

```
git diff [--options] --cached [<commit>] [--] [<path>…​]
```

`--cached` can be switched with `--staged` if it easier for you to remember. In documentation *index, staging and cached* are all used to mean the same thing.

This answers the question *What my next commit will look like?*

**Extra**
To compare *working directory* with *HEAD* use:

```
git diff $(git rev-parse --short HEAD) [--] [<path>…​]
```

Comment: so `git diff` without any options compares worktree with index? And `git diff --cached` compares index with HEAD by default?

Comment: *Index, staging and cached* means the same thing, and is used in documentation interchangeably...

Answer (score 0):

what? First `staging area` and `index` are the same. Then, git diff compares HEAD+index (so to speak) with your working tree.

Comment: Well, that's inaccurate. `staging area` and `index` are the same and they are used interchangeably extensibly if you look around. Your working tree is your working tree.

Comment: actually you are right, I gave you an upvote...MrCholo approves